# Cannot instantiate the editor in Angular

Tags: angular, web

I am trying to build a code editor

I have component which renders conditionally

```
 <ace-editor [(text)]="text" #editor style="height:150px;"></ace-editor>
```

And I have a ngAfterViewInit Lifecycle hook in which I am setting all the editor options.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
console.log('After view init called...');
this.editor.setTheme('monokai');
this.editor.setMode('text');
this.editor.getEditor().setShowPrintMargin(false);
this.editor.getEditor().setFontSize(16);
// this.editor.setReadOnly(true);
this.editor.getEditor().setOptions({
  // enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
});

this.editor.getEditor().commands.addCommand({
  name: 'showOtherCompletions',
  bindKey: 'Ctrl-.',
  exec: function (editor) {},
});
```

}

I am accessing the editor using the template reference variable using the @ViewChild inside of my .ts file. But in the browser I am getting Cannot read property setTheme of undefined.

Comment: did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's related to `Metadata Properties` of your `@ViewChild` in .ts file.

You can find them here
https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

In this case, you can change the static property of your ViewChild.
something like this:

```
 @ViewChild('viewMe', { static: true })
```

If you post more about the .ts file, it would be easier to tell what's happening.

UPDATE:

based on the comment:
The reason of that error is inside of ngAfterViewInit your `<ace-editor #editor></<ace-editor>` is not ready so `this.editor` is undefined. you should change the logic or call all of `this.editor.XXX`, at the time when `<ace-editor #editor></<ace-editor>` is rendered.

Comment: `@ViewChild('editor') editor: AceEditorComponent;
ngAfterViewInit()     
    this.editor.setTheme('eclipse');
    this.editor.setMode('text');
    this.editor.getEditor().setShowPrintMargin(false);
    this.editor.getEditor().setFontSize(16);
    // this.editor.setReadOnly(true);
    this.editor.getEditor().setOptions({
      // enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    });

    this.editor.getEditor().commands.addCommand({
      name: 'showOtherCompletions',
      bindKey: 'Ctrl-.',
      exec: function (editor) {},
    });
  }`